# How to specify what code is covered by a unit-test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

In PHPunit there is [`@covers`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.specifying-covered-methods) annotation to specify which classes/methods/functions are covered by a specific unit test. This helps avoiding false-coverage.

Is there a way to do something similar in the Python unit-test world?

I am using Python 3.6 with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) for unit-testing and am free to choose any coverage tool that will allow me to annotate or mark my tests with what code (unit) they do cover and do not cover.

I am hoping for something like annotations or pragma comments to be used in the unit-tests. Preferably supported by the PyCharm if possible.

Comment: Have you found any solution to the problem? Is it not supported in python world?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I am encouraging and looking forward to discussing such feature with developers of the [pytest](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/graphs/contributors)